# PyCharm coverage only measures test directory for a GAE app with Selenium tests

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, selenium, code-coverage, pycharm

I'm developing a GAE app in Python using the PyCharm IDE. I have developed an initial set of Selenium WebDriver unit tests, which are in directory "test", with "test" at the top level of the project directory. Note that my tests do not directly call the GAE modules. They only utilize Selenium, which in turn runs the app thru a browser.

When I use menu option "Run 'Unittests in test' with coverage", I get a report showing coverage within directory "test", and also the colors show up in the left margin for the Python modules in "test". The information looks accurate. Very cool!

However, the rest of the files in my project show "not covered", even though the tests exercise a lot of that code via Selenium remote control of a browser.

In settings, I've tried checking "Use bundled coverage.py" and, after running `sudo pip install coverage`, I've also tried unchecking "Use bundled coverage.py". My results are the same either way.

Is it possible that you simply cannot obtain coverage of a GAE app being exercised via Selenium?